# Sumarizar más de una columna en objeto COM de Excel

Tags: excel, vba, com

Estoy usando por primera vez subtotal en una hoja Excel generada desde Openedge ABL.

El ejemplo de la KB (https://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/Sample-Code-to-do-Excel-Grouping) es:
**chWorksheet:Range("A1"):CurrentRegion:Subtotal(1, -4112, 2, True, False, False).**

Los parámetros para SubTotal son:
**GroupBy , Function:, TotalList, Replace:, PageBreaks:, SummaryBelowData:**

En "TotalList" el ejemplo es 2 es decir que se totaliza la columna 2.

En VBA, TotalList puede ser un array. Por ejemplo Array(14, 15) indica totalizar las columnas 14 y 15.

Pero no he conseguido que ABL acepte eso. sólo me recibe un número entero para una columna.

¿Sabe alguien si hay manera de pedir totalizar más de una columna?

Muchas gracias.

Comment: Bienvenido a SO. Tendrías que mirar como van los Arrays en ABL, porque en VBA como bien dices funciona perfectamente.

Comment: Yo creía haberlo intentado pero parece que no.
Envié ahora una variable entera de arreglo con los números de columnas y funcionó a la perfección, ¡muchas gracias!

Comment: Si encontraste la solución, postea tu propia respuesta para que servir en el futuro a otras personas

Comment: Hecho, muchas gracias. ¿Debería yo aceptar mi propia respuesta, o el bot de Stack Overflow me quitaría puntos?

Comment: Sí puedes :) [¿Puedo responder a mi propia pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer#:~:text=Para%20alentar%20a%20las%20personas,p%C3%A1gina%20de%20Hacer%20una%20Pregunta.)

Comment: De nuevo, ¡muchas gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enviando una variable entera de arreglo (INTEGER EXTENT) con los números de columnas, funcionó a la perfección. Muchas gracias, Elier, por la ayuda.